# how to check the data downloaded when i open my website

Tags: browser

I was looking for a tool which give me the size of downloaded data when i open some website 
like when i open Gmail.com , it says

> downloaded data : 2.012.544 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Firefox, just right click on the website and select Page Info. It already shows you the size.

[image]